# how can i cope with classes in python?

Tags: python

I don't know what is wrong here that when I run the code nothing happens! here is the code:

```
class Stack():
    "A container with a last-in-first-out (LIFO) queuing policy."

    def __init__(self,list=[]):
        self.list =list

    def push(self, item):
        "Push 'item' onto the stack"
        return self.list.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        "Pop the most recently pushed item from the stack"
        return self.list.pop()

s=Stack([6,7])

s.push(5)
```

I expect to see s is created as a list [6,7] and then 5 is added to it. but nothing happens. what should I do?

Comment: You need to `print(s.list)`

Comment: So what did you expect to happen instead? If nothing happens, *your code ran without errors*. You don't have any print calls in your code so no output will be produced.

Comment: You don't need any of those imports for this question.

Comment: thank u all!  what Kpie said worked. I had used print(s) but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
import inspect
import heapq
import random

class Stack():

  "A container with a last-in-first-out (LIFO) queuing policy."

  def __init__(self,list=[]):
   self.list =list
  def push(self, item):
    print("Push 'item' onto the stack")
    return self.list.append(item)

  def pop(self):
    print("Pop the most recently pushed item from the stack")
    return self.list.pop()

  def printObj(self):
    print("Printing stackObj: ")
    for x in self.list:
      print(x)

s=Stack([6,7])

s.push(5)
s.printObj()
```

As far as I can tell it is doing what you want, you just forgot your `prints` :)

Comment: thanks for the reply!  print(s.list) worked but with what u said an error happened:                                                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AI\proj1\myexample.py", line 27, in <module>
    s.printObj()
AttributeError: Stack instance has no attribute 'printObj'

Comment: did you add the `def printObj(self):` method to your class? What looks to be happening is your `Stack` object is not recognizing the method - either its not defined or there is a scoping issue

Comment: sorry! i had just forgot to define the func. u were right!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is *almost* fine. You just need to print something to see a result!

I just want to point you a pretty nasty error that you have. You are using a mutating type as default parameter! Look at this example:

```
s=Stack()
s.push(1)
s2=Stack()
print(s2.list) # should be empty
```

This code actually print `[1]` ! Please read this [article](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) for more information.